# Clear QList that is being used by QSerial

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following bit of code:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updatecommstatus()));
timer -> start();

void MainWindow::updatecommstatus()
{
    const auto infos = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    for (const QSerialPortInfo &info : infos) {
        QString s = QObject::tr("Port: ") + info.portName() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Location: ") + info.systemLocation() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Description: ") + info.description() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Manufacturer: ") + info.manufacturer() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Serial number: ") + info.serialNumber() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Vendor Identifier: ") + (info.hasVendorIdentifier() ? QString::number(info.vendorIdentifier(), 16) : QString()) + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Product Identifier: ") + (info.hasProductIdentifier() ? QString::number(info.productIdentifier(), 16) : QString()) + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Busy: ") + (info.isBusy() ? QObject::tr("Yes") : QObject::tr("No")) + "\n";
        if (QString::number(info.vendorIdentifier(), 16) == "16d0" && QString::number(info.productIdentifier(), 16) == "650")
        {
            ui->label_commport->setText(info.portName());
        }
        else 
        {
            ui->label_commport->setText("COM Error");
        }
    }
}
```

It is utilising QSerial to display all the available COM ports info. I want to display the portName in a label when certain `vendorIdentifierand` and `productIdentifier` match some number.

The above code works well when the device is plugged in (my label displays the right information). But I want to have it when I unplug it that the label displays COM Error. This part does not work. The above code is being targetted by a QTimer and updated, but the `Qlist infos` is not clearing. Basically, how can I clear this Qlist ? `infos.clear();` does not work.

Comment: is this the full example? Looks here like your `infos` is a local stack member and not something that you can be globally `clear()`ing

Comment: not to mention that it's `const` so i doubt a call to `clear()` would allow this to compile

Comment: @yankee2905 I updated with full example.

Comment: Or probably if nothing is attached you don't even enter the for so nothing changes. Try checking also if infos is empty. You don't need to clear the info list as it is a local variable, popped from the stack each time `updatecommstatus()` method returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lucaAngiolini alluded to in his comment, the scope of you label update seems wrong. I think your trying to do actually compile all available ports into a string, and then set the label thereafter.

```
void MainWindow::updatecommstatus()
{
    const auto infos = QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts();
    QStringList comport_labels;
    if (infos.empty())
        comprt_labels << "COM Error";
    for (const QSerialPortInfo &info : infos) {
        QString s = QObject::tr("Port: ") + info.portName() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Location: ") + info.systemLocation() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Description: ") + info.description() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Manufacturer: ") + info.manufacturer() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Serial number: ") + info.serialNumber() + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Vendor Identifier: ") + (info.hasVendorIdentifier() ? QString::number(info.vendorIdentifier(), 16) : QString()) + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Product Identifier: ") + (info.hasProductIdentifier() ? QString::number(info.productIdentifier(), 16) : QString()) + "\n"
                    + QObject::tr("Busy: ") + (info.isBusy() ? QObject::tr("Yes") : QObject::tr("No")) + "\n";
        if (QString::number(info.vendorIdentifier(), 16) == "16d0" && QString::number(info.productIdentifier(), 16) == "650")
        {
            comport_labels << info.portName();
        }
        else 
        {
            comport_labels << "COM Error";
        }
    }

    ui->label_commport->setText(comport_labels.join(","));
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working more correctly -- yes I understand where I was going wrong. The only thing now is when unplugged it doesn't display "COM Error". It displays nothing...

Comment: added an empty check to handle that case :)